# ASP.Net Regular Expression Validator no spaces

Tags: asp.net, regex, validation

I'm trying to set up a validation expression for an ASP.Net Regular Expression Validator control. It is for validating the creation of a user name, so I want to limit the number of characters, and I also want to prevent them from using spaces. Here's what I've got so far:

```
^.*(?=.{5,20})(?=.*\w{5,255}).*$
```

The `\w{5,255}` part prevents spaces and special characters (except for underscores, apparently). I have no idea how "5,255" makes it work, but it does; I just copied it from somewhere else.

The main problem I'm having is that if the first or last character is a space (or special character), it passes validation, which is not acceptable. Can anyone help me? I'm sure it is something simple, but I know next to nothing about regular expressions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use something simpler like this:

`^[a-zA-Z0-9_]{5,255}$`

This will allow alphanumeric usernames between 5-255 characters in length.

Comment: What about underscores? I'd like to allow underscores as well, which the original one does, somehow.

Comment: See my update. If you need any other character, just add them inside the `[]`.

Comment: Or just use `^\w{5,255}$`, since `\w` is effectively shorthand for `[a-zA-Z0-9_]`.

Comment: @Steve: with the disclaimer that `\w` will allow non-ascii aplhanums as well.

Comment: Well, of course. Depends on how the data's transmitted across the wire, though, right?

Comment: what if i want to not allow spaces at all and other validation checking sever side i want expression to check only whitespce

Comment: @Anish: Not sure if I follow. Can you post a separate question with some specifics?

Answer (score 2):

(let's expand overall understanding of how to at least use regex!)

The main reason why the posted regex wasn't working is because you were attempting to use lookahead. Lookahead is a 0-length pattern that just guarantees that the next part of the string will match a certain pattern (and is usually used to take advantage of it being 0-length, so it doesn't expand your capturing group).

Effectively, what your regex (going off of the original `/^.(?=.{5,20})(?=.\w{5,255}).*$/`) meant was:

`^.` "The beginning of our line should match any single character (provided it's not a newline, although this depends on the regex implementation as well as flags that may or may not have been passed in)"

`(?=` "and guarantee that after here"

`.{5,20})` are any 5-20 characters."

`(?=` "Also, after that same first character (since, remember, lookahead is 0-length), guarantee"

`.` "one arbitrary character"

`\w{5,255})` "and 5-255 word characters."

`.*$` And of course, since all of that exhaustive matching was 0-length, we want the rest of the line to be an arbitrary number of characters."

What you technically could have done to use lookaround was `^(?=\w{5,255}).{5,255}$`, but that's just overly convoluted. I'd suggest just using `\w{5,255}` or something along those lines.